# What is the asymptotic expansion of a function defined by a converging power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, power-series

Given an analytic function $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!}z^n$, how could one go about finding the asymptotic expansion of $f(z)$ for $z\to\infty$?

In particular given $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}z^n$, what are the methods one could try to find an asymptotic expansion of $g$ for $z\to\infty$, if one doesn't have an integral representation of the function?

Comment: You migh twant to look at 'order and type' in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Comment: The power series of the function $g(z)$ you gave as an example converges for $|z|<1$. You would first need to extend it outside the unit circle. @KaviRamaMurthy The problem is that the given example is not an entire function.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful remark @Gary I've changed the example to function that is entire. Any suggestions how I could go about finding the asymptotics expansion of $g(z)$ for $z\to\infty$?

Comment: This can be helpful: https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#iii Your particular example can be expressed in terms of the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ (http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E5) and so $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!n}}x^n }  = \operatorname{Ei}(x) - \gamma  - \log x \sim \frac{{e^x }}{x}\left( {1 + \frac{{1!}}{x} + \frac{{2!}}{{x^2 }} +  \cdots } \right)
$$ as $x\to +\infty$ (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.E2).